# Localized text not showing for Privacy alert in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, plist

I am developing an iOS application which supports English and Arabic. User can change the application language from inside the app. 
When user changes the language  I am setting it like ,

```
    //change app language
UserDefaults.standard.set([language], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
currentLanguage = language
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()



 //current language updating

var currentLanguage : String{
        get{
                if let selectedLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedLanguage"){
                    return selectedLanguage
                }else{
                    let language = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
                    if language.hasPrefix("ar"){
                        return SupportedLanguage.ar.rawValue
                    }else{
                        return SupportedLanguage.en.rawValue
                    }
                }
        }
        set{
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "selectedLanguage")
        }
    }
```

In this way, App is not exiting. Just reloading the root view controller

The issue I am facing is, when I change the application language like this, the privacy alerts like “..requesting permission for using Location”, “… would ,like to use Photo album” etc are not showing in the selected language. I have created InfoPlist.string files for English and Arabic and added like

NSCameraUsageDescription = ".... would like to access Camera";
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription = ".... wants to use your current location for better usability";

Still its not showing. Also I tried deleting, cleaning app, deleting derived data.

Any idea why its happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `AppleLanguages` key needs app to be restarted so new localization applied , you can try to use `NSLocalizedString` with tableName or change current bundle you read from , but system localization won't be changed until app restarted

Comment: Yes, I am  using NSlocalizedString with table name for getting other localized text in app. 'func localize() -> String{
  guard let bundle = Bundle.main.path(forResource: LanguageHandler.sharedLanguageHandler.currentLanguage, ofType: "lproj") else {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, comment: "")
   }

  let langBundle = Bundle(path:bundle)
  return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: langBundle!, value: "", comment: "")
 }'  But this privacy alerts are automatically showing by taking from respective string files right? Correct me if its wrong.

Comment: Privacy alerts won't be changed until app restarted read from table will work for your own alerts

Comment: oh thats sad :(